# javascript Button not updating the html value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, textbox

I am still fairly new to JS and am having an issue updating a value of a textbox so that it passes the value through to the MVC Model.  Currently the code semi works, and by that I mean that when you click the button it updates the text but not the value so the incorrect value is being passed to my model.  Lets hope I don't mess this up in the cleanup for the post.  :)  The HTML side of the code looks like this:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr class="manageItems-spacer" />
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.DefaultItem)
                @if(Model.DefaultItem != null)
                { 
                    @Html.TbbTextBoxFor(x => x.DefaultItem, new { disabled = "disabled" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DefaultItem);
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ListBox("AssignedItems", new MultiSelectList(Model.Items, "Id", "FriendlyDisplay"), new { @size = 5 })
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="javascript:editItem.setDefault()")>Set Default</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here is the view source HTML:

```
<table class="manageItems">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Items</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="manageItems-spacer" />
        <tr>
            <td>

                <label for="DefaultItem">Default Item</label>
        <input disabled="disabled" id="DefaultItem" name="DefaultItem" type="text" value="1234" />
        <input id="DefaultItem" name="DefaultItem" type="hidden" value="1234" />                
    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="AssignedItems" multiple="multiple" name="AssignedItems" size="5">
            <option value="1">8526</option>
            <option value="2">1234</option>
            <option value="11">9988565</option>
        </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="AssignedItems" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="javascript:editUser.setDefault()" >Set Default</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the code for the setDefault button that it calls:

```
this.setDefault = function () {
    var selectedItem = $("#AssignedItems option:selected").text();

    document.getElementById("DefaultItem").innerHTML = selectedItem;
    document.getElementById("DefaultItem").value = selectedItem;
};
```

For the value to even be passed from the HTML view to the controller I had to add the HiddenFor code in the HTML otherwise it would pass a null value.  The other things I have tried after searching the net is adding the .innerHTML to update the value but it does not work either.  I have also found posts talking about adding the window.onload but I was not able to get that to work correctly either.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: 1) Show your actual HTML, not your .NET code - this is a client-side issue. Your server-side code has no relevance here. 2) You never need to specify `javascript:` in an event handler.

Comment: Diodeus,
  I added the HTML to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Removed the disabled and changed it to readonly and I am now able to set the value.